# error in initializing stringstream

Tags: c++, stream

I don't understand why I got this error message at line "if (sentToGroup(client_fd, ss) == -1){"
While running the following code:

```
   stringstream ss;
    // ss.get();
    ss << "test";
    if (sentToGroup(client_fd, ss) == -1){
        perror("Fail sending to group");
    }
```

I got the error message below, why??

```
Initializing argument 2 of ‘int sentToGroup(int, std::stringstream)’
```

The sentToGroup function is as below:

```
int sentToGroup(int sender_fd, stringstream str){
    char buffer[MAX];
    stringstream sender;
    sender << int(sender_fd) << "> " << str;
    int bytes = recv(sender_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    for (int c = printerCnt; c < sizeof(printer); c++){
        if (printer[c] != sender_fd){
            if (send(printer[c], sender, bytes, 0) == -1){
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try changing the prototype of sentToGroup as int sentToGroup(int sender_fd, stringstream & str)

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear how that message is produced, but `stringstream` is not copyable. You should pass by reference and copy data out of it, if you do not wish to pass a `stringstream` but not modify it.

However, you typically should not pass a `stringstream` at all. If the purpose is to pass a string into the function, use `string`. If the purpose is to treat it as a stream, use `istream &` or `ostream &` or `iostream &`. You can still pass the same `stringstream` because of polymorphism.

I'm not really sure what you're doing here, but changing `stringstream` to `iostream &` should fix the immediate problem and possible later issues too.

Comment: Any specific reasons for not passing stringstream reference? Just out of curiosity

Comment: @hype: using the base class allows other types of stream to be used. `stringstream` provides essentially no features beyond `iostream` except using a particular `streambuf` upon construction, so requiring the more derived class is pointlessly restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy `stringstream`, try to pass it by reference:

```
int sentToGroup(int sender_fd, stringstream& str)
```